# How to bind action sheet in array list using ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have posts list and each post has a report action sheet. I want to make like when the user clicks on repost, switch action sheet text Repost to Undo Repost. I try it but it's working with page refresh or API call again not working without refresh page.

page.html

```
<ion-col *ngIf="feed.IsReusable" class="colsuccess" tappable (click)="repostActionSheet(feed.PostId);$event.stopPropagation();">
   <ion-icon name="repeat"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span *ngIf="feed.ReusableCount > 0">{{feed.ReusableCount}}</span>
</ion-col>
<ion-col *ngIf="!feed.IsReusable" class="coldark" tappable (click)="repostActionSheet(feed.PostId);$event.stopPropagation();">
   <ion-icon name="repeat"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span *ngIf="feed.ReusableCount > 0">{{feed.ReusableCount}}</span>
</ion-col>
```

Here I am checking `feed.IsReusable` means when I click on action sheet repost, a database entry is like 0 and 1. Also when I get list data `IsReusable` i am getting 0 or 1. It looks like this.

[image]

page.ts

```
...
public IsReusable: boolean;
...

async repostActionSheet(PostId: number) {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Repost',
        role: 'destructive',
        icon: 'repeat',
        handler: () => {
          this.storage.get('userID').then(async (loggedinUId) => {
            const value: {
              LoginUserId: string,
              PostId: number,
            } = {
              LoginUserId: loggedinUId,
              PostId: PostId,
            };
            const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
              message: 'Please wait...',
            });
            loading.present().then(() => {
              if (this.storage.get("userID") != null) {
                this.apiService.repost(value).then(async (success) => {
                  if (success = 0) {
                    console.log(success, "Update success.");
                    this.IsReusable = !this.IsReusable;
                    this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
                      this.feedlist = data;
                      loading.dismiss();
                    });
                  } else {
                    this.IsReusable = !this.IsReusable;
                    this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
                      this.feedlist = data;
                      loading.dismiss();
                    });
                  }
                }, err => {
                  loading.dismiss();
                  console.log("Error", err);
                });
              }
            });
          })
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Repost with comment',
        icon: 'create',
        handler: () => {
          this.storage.get('userID').then(async (loggedinUId) => {
            const modal = await this.modalController.create({
              component: RepostWithCommentPage,
              keyboardClose: false,
              componentProps: {
                selectedpostId: PostId,
              }
            });
            modal.onDidDismiss()
              .then(() => {
                this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
                  this.feedlist = data;
                });
              });

            return await modal.present();
          })
        }
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
```

In the action sheet also I try to like this `text: feed.IsReusable ? 'Repost' : 'Undo Repost',` but it's working only when I refresh the page.

Is there any way to do this without a page refresh?

Comment: can you tell me about list

Comment: @Utpaul I have a list of posts, in the post have action sheet and two option is Repost and Repost with comment